# Marshalling a VARIANT back from COM to C++ client

Tags: c++, com, marshalling, atl

I'm attempting to marshal a safearray of BSTRs from a COM object, back to a C++ client application.

My IDL definition of the function involved:

```
[id(5), helpstring("method GetStreams")] 
    HRESULT GetStreams( [out,retval] VARIANT* pvarStreamNames );
```

Here's my implementation of the GetStreams() function:

```
STDMETHODIMP CArchiveManager::GetStreams(VARIANT* pvarStreamNames)
{   
CComSafeArray<BSTR, VT_BSTR>    saStreamNames;
CComVariant                     varOutNames;

Stream* pNext       = NULL;
int     nNumStreams = m_Streams.NumStreams();

if( nNumStreams == 0 )
    return S_OK;

for(int x = 0; x < nNumStreams; x++)
{
    pNext = m_Streams.GetAt(x); 
    if( pNext )             
        saStreamNames.Add( pNext->StreamName() );   
}

if( saStreamNames.GetCount() > 0 )
{
    varOutNames.vt      = VT_ARRAY;
    varOutNames.parray  = saStreamNames.m_psa;

    varOutNames.Detach(pvarStreamNames);
}

return S_OK;
}
```

Here's how the C++ client program calls the GetStreams() function:

```
VARIANT varStreamNames;
hr = spArchiveMgr->GetStreams( &varStreamNames );
```

I trace through the program using the interactive debugger and everything appears to work correctly (safearray populates correctly, etc) until the GetStreams() function returns.  At that point, I get an "unhandled exception reading location" message.

advice on how to debug/solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two problems. The first one is

```
 VARIANT varStreamNames;
```

is unitialized, so when

```
varOutNames.Detach(pvarStreamNames);
```

runs it calls `VariantClear()` on an uninitialized variable and this leads to undefined behavior - your program crashes.

You have to call `VariantInit()` on `varStreamNames` before invoking the COM method or just use `CComVariant` type for `varStreamNames`.

The second one is:

```
CComSafeArray<BSTR, VT_BSTR>    saStreamNames;
CComVariant                     varOutNames;

varOutNames.vt      = VT_ARRAY;
varOutNames.parray  = saStreamNames.m_psa;
```

perfoms shallow copy of the safe array - now both `saStreamNames` and `varOutNames` own  the safe array and so when `saStreamNames` gets destroyed  at the end of the scope the safe array is released.

Since you've copied the same safe array address into `pvarStreamNames` you've now got a variant with a dangling safe array pointer. Trying to access that safe array is undefined behavior. You should use `Detach()` method of `CComSafeArray` to release ownership.

Comment: I've tried using the CComVariant type on the client side, alas, I'm still getting the same error, and at the same point

Comment: @freefallr: Yeap, there was a one more problem there.