# Return Array of object from ATL ActiveX Control

Tags: c++, com, mfc, activex

I have an existing ActiveX control that I need to add a method that returns an array of objects.
the object is a type that I need to create, how do I go about returning an array of objects ?

Answer (score 3):

You return a safe array or - my preference - a variant value holding safe array, e.g. array of variants. This is well recognized by various ActiveX hosting environments, including scripting languages.

- [How to Create Variant Array in ATL COM and pass back to VB](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00463b8f-adb2-44a6-a8ff-12b44bc3c5f3/how-to-create-variant-array-in-atl-com-and-pass-back-to-vb?forum=vcgeneral)
- [Using COM to Pass Arrays](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/com/article.php/c2577/Using-COM-to-Pass-Arrays.htm)
- [returning a VARIANT array from a ATL server](http://computer-programming-forum.com/77-vc-atl/ab8b65acb939e383.htm)
- [atl object with variant array [out] parameter do not work for vbscript](http://computer-programming-forum.com/77-vc-atl/3a0c1361c1ca4aa4.htm)
- [Getting arrays to/from a custom activex function](http://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=40891.5;wap2)
- [Marshalling a VARIANT back from COM to C++ client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204488/marshalling-a-variant-back-from-com-to-c-client)

Comment: correction: I am using MFC ActiveX control, not ATL.

Comment: It was worth putting onto question (you tagged the question with [tag:atl], and not [tag:mfc]), however it does not change much: same IDL syntax, variants and safe arrays, just possibly slightly different wrappers and C++ side code.